# How to create an index of a several variables that best summarizes them?

Tags: correlation, pca, valuation

I want to describe the "influence" of some internet content, where "influence" is loosely defined as its virality/popularity among the audience. For each link, I have information such as the number of clicks, views, favorites, shares, etc. I'd like to turn them into a single index.

Intuitively, some factors should be weighted more than other (e.g. shares should be more "influential" than views), but how should I calculate their weights? PCA seems like an option, but are there other good methods (especially in the case where the 1st component of PCA summarizes a lower percentage of the data)?

Comment: Do you have a direct measurement of "popularity"?

Comment: @whuber - No, I don't have a direct measurement of popularity. It is what I need to "invent" so to say.

Comment: That's the right word: you're making up the answer.  There's nothing wrong with that, as long as (1) you recognize what you're going and (2) you don't claim your invention is the result of some kind of statistical analysis.

Answer (score 1):

PCA sounds like a good answer if you want to assume that there *is* a single axis of popularity - i.e. that a post that is more likely to have many shares is also likely to have many clicks or likes. If this is the case, your first component should capture variation in most or all of these variables and explain a large part of the data.

If your PCA returns a number of components which each explains a fair amount of the data, but no one of which explains a majority, that suggests to me that the underlying assumption is somewhat flawed, and that in fact "popularity" in this case is used to refer to a number of metrics that need not coincide. Or, in other words, that there are several and perhaps conflicting ways that a post can be popular. In that case, maybe a principal component won't be the best index for you, but you'll still have learned something about your data and your assumptions. :)